# How can I regain ownership of my question after it has been migrated to another site?

Tags: support, specific-question, migrated-questions

I ran into serious trouble with PostgreSQL and asked for help here:

[PostGres with 62 GB of table gobbling up over 500 GB on disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76223654/postgres-with-62-gb-of-table-gobbling-up-over-500-gb-on-disk?noredirect=1)

My question was moved to another Stack Exchange site:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/326988/postgres-with-62-gb-of-table-gobbling-up-over-500-gb-on-disk

I guess that's OK—obviously, the voters who chose to migrate it thought it belonged better on that site. I don't have enough experience to judge whether that action is correct. **My concern here (in this Meta question) is only the effect that the migration had on me and my experience.**

After migration to the other site, I cannot even comment on my own question because I need a score of at least 50, which I don't have on that other site.

How can I regain ownership of my question after it has been migrated to another site so that I have full privileges to interact with it (e.g., to edit it, comment on it, comment on the answers, accept an answer, etc.)?

Comment: Your question was migrated because it is more suitable for the other site, as it is a database administration question, not a code related question. Also, you don't need to *comment* on your own question. You can edit it instead, which requires no minimum reputation. The edit link on all [se] sites can be found in the lower left corner of the question, below the tags.

Comment: Does https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31009 answer your question?

Comment: A question about migration that got migrated!  Is there a badge for that?

Comment: There is no minimum reputation required to comment on your own question or on answers to your own question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's not obvious, but you can easily take ownership of the question when you create an account on the other Stack Exchange site, by clicking either the login or signup buttons on the right of the header navbar.

Once you have created an account (/profile) on the other site, it will automatically reassociate the migrated posts to your new account which would give you the normal post owner privileges, e.g. the ability to comments on answers to your question, unilateral editing of your post, etc.